# Find the leading order uniform approximation to the boundary value problem $\epsilon y''+y'\sin x+y\sin 2x = 0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics

$$\epsilon y''+y'\sin x+y\sin 2x = 0$$ with boundary conditions $y(0)=\pi$ and $y(\pi)=0$ as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$. I don't know how to find out where the boundary layer is? I thought initially it was at x=0 but this just leads to the outer solution of $$y=Ae^{-2\sin x}$$ if i've done it correctly and applying the boundary conditions means A=0 which means its not a boundary layer. I'm so lost. Any hints? Thanks!